Trigger Jenkins Jobs every 10 seconds
Able to configure jenkins jobs every minute, but is there a way to configure jenkins jobs to be triggered every 10 seconds or every second?
I have come accross poll-scm and throttle, but I did not find any of it useful.
Any suggesstion will be helpful.

Configured the job to be executed every minute and then added below code in the execute shell

for i in {1..6}  # Loop runs 6 times
do
  echo "Executing task $i at $(date)"
  # Add your commands to run the task here
  
  sleep 1  # Sleep for 1 second before the next iteration
done

I could not find a  better way, please so let me know if you know the correct way to handle it.

I am going to assume you are not building an app every second, you are probably polling something. Polling at that frequency should be done with a continuously running process, not separate job runs. Jobs are relatively heavy, every run creates multiple files across multiple folders, interacts (typically over the network) with an scm, spawns processes on agents (again, typically over the network). That's a lot of overhead if you are just polling. Even if you somehow coerce Jenkins to do it that would be wildly suboptimal.
